# Query in mysql (phpadmin) works but not in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have problem when trying to import the automatic generated PHP code from MySQL into PHP.

Server Info:
MySQL verson: Server-versjon: 5.6.25
PHP verson: 5.6.11

My database consist of 3 tables who are joind together with foreignkeys etc.

ansatt, timer , prosjekt

this are my query in MySQL:

```
SELECT ansatt.brukernavn, timer.bruker_id_fk, timer.dag,timer.timer, timer.overtid_50, timer.overtid_100, timer.km, prosjekt.prosjekt_navn FROM ansatt JOIN timer ON ansatt.brukerid = timer.bruker_id_fk JOIN prosjekt ON timer.prosjekt_id_fk = prosjekt.prosjekt_id WHERE ansatt.brukerid = 11
```

this are provideing me with the following [successful result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5q0w.jpg)

any when i use the following generated code in my .php file

```
$sqlget = "SELECT ansatt.brukernavn, timer.bruker_id_fk, timer.dag, timer.timer, timer.overtid_50, timer.overtid_100, timer.km, prosjekt.prosjekt_navn\n"
    . "FROM ansatt\n"
    . "JOIN timer ON ansatt.brukerid = timer.bruker_id_fk\n"
    . "JOIN prosjekt ON timer.prosjekt_id_fk = prosjekt.prosjekt_id\n"
    . "WHERE ansatt.brukerid = 11";

    date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Oslo");

    $sqldata = mysqli_query($dbcon, $sqlget) or die ('kunne ikke hente info');
echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr><th>Dato</th><th>Prosjekt</th><th>Std. Arb.Timer</th><th>Overtid 50%</th><th>Overtid 100%</th><th>Km</th>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqldata, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        echo "<tr><td>";
        echo $row['dag'];
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo $row['prosjekt_navn'];
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo $row['timer'];
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo $row['overtid_50'];
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo $row['overtid_100'];
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo $row['km'];
        echo "</td><td>";       
    }
    echo "</table>"
```

It will show following records:
[working php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyMRj.jpg) and everything is fine, but when i try to change the format of date in MySQL with the following query

```
SELECT ansatt.brukernavn, timer.bruker_id_fk, DATE_FORMAT(timer.dag,'%d-%m-%Y'), timer.timer, timer.overtid_50, timer.overtid_100, timer.km, prosjekt.prosjekt_navn FROM ansatt JOIN timer ON ansatt.brukerid = timer.bruker_id_fk JOIN prosjekt ON timer.prosjekt_id_fk = prosjekt.prosjekt_id WHERE ansatt.brukerid = 11
```

everything is fine and provideing me with a successful result and formated date dd.mm.yyyy. When i clicking on the generate PHPcode in PHPadmin it are showign me this code:

```
$sqlget = "SELECT ansatt.brukernavn, timer.bruker_id_fk, DATE_FORMAT(timer.dag,\'%d-%m-%Y\'), timer.timer, timer.overtid_50, timer.overtid_100, timer.km, prosjekt.prosjekt_navn FROM ansatt JOIN timer ON ansatt.brukerid = timer.bruker_id_fk JOIN prosjekt ON timer.prosjekt_id_fk = prosjekt.prosjekt_id WHERE ansatt.brukerid = 11";
```

When i refresh the site it could not get a any data from

```
$sqldata = mysqli_query($dbcon, $sqlget) or die ('kunne ikke hente info');
```

when i remove the following code

> DATE_FORMAT(timer.dag,\'%d-%m-%Y\')

and replace by just "timer.dag" it will work again  showing the dates in yyyy.mm.dd as default.

I have tried to search for a answear on the forums and the web and i cant find a matching answer that solve this problem or point into the right direction

im sorry if my grammar is not the best and sorry if this are already being answered before. Hope someone here have the answer, i can provide a copy of the db for those who are interrested and need it.

Comment: delete those \n and try again

Comment: Replace \n with space.

Comment: Also fix output of your table to produce valid `html`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Output the mysql error with

```
$sqldata = mysqli_query($dbcon, $sqlget) or die ('kunne ikke hente info. Error: ' . mysqli_error($dbcon));
```

What is the type of the field timer.dag?

Try setting a name for the calculated field like this:

```
... DATE_FORMAT(timer.dag, '%d-%m-%Y') AS dag, ...
```

Comment: it are setup as  "date" field in the database

Comment: By not useing / I dont get any error and the  result is showing but the date row is empty

Comment: by DATE_FORMAT(timer.dag, '%d-%m-%Y') AS dag as you suggestet did work . now it display everything correct. Thanks for your help

Comment: You are welcome. But you marked the wrong Answer as the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

In your query

```
$sqlget = "SELECT ansatt.brukernavn, timer.bruker_id_fk, DATE_FORMAT(timer.dag,\'%d-%m-%Y\'), timer.timer, timer.overtid_50, timer.overtid_100, timer.km, prosjekt.prosjekt_navn FROM ansatt JOIN timer ON ansatt.brukerid = timer.bruker_id_fk JOIN prosjekt ON timer.prosjekt_id_fk = prosjekt.prosjekt_id WHERE ansatt.brukerid = 11";
```

The simple quotes in DATE_FORMAT does not need to be escaped with a `\`

Try with this one :

```
$sqlget = "SELECT ansatt.brukernavn, timer.bruker_id_fk, DATE_FORMAT(timer.dag,'%d-%m-%Y'), timer.timer, timer.overtid_50, timer.overtid_100, timer.km, prosjekt.prosjekt_navn FROM ansatt JOIN timer ON ansatt.brukerid = timer.bruker_id_fk JOIN prosjekt ON timer.prosjekt_id_fk = prosjekt.prosjekt_id WHERE ansatt.brukerid = 11";
```

I hope it will help you

Comment: Did try without \ and it did show the result but the date was empty